# Have Image take up as much of window as possible, without exceeding borders

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Now the title of the question may have been worded the wrong way.

I want the image to take up 100% of the width or heigh (I guess whichever is larger). Kind of like when you have a photoviewer and there make be a black border on the sides or the top, depending which way it is.

Obviously if it's a very small image I don't want it to stretch, I never want any of the images to stretch, I just want them to fill as much of the window out as they can.

For example, when you load an image on Google, it doesn't show it's fullest resolution. It shrinks it down to fit within the borders of the page if it is to big. Then you can click on it to zoom in if you want.

How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would actually need the following:

```
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

This requires a container with an explicit height set to work.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AtxYb/4/

Comment: @MohammadAdil I've updated my answer, it requires a container with an explicit height set to work

Comment: @MohammadAdil From what I understand the poster doesn't want that. They never want the image to stretch

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to accomplish with CSS alone:

```
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The `max-width` ensures that it never exceeds 100% of the width of its container. `height` tells the browser to size the image normally (eg. it's not going to stretch it width-wise, but not height-wise) and is included for older browsers.

You can of course also reverse this if you wish to match a container's height instead of width.

edit:

As pburgess suggests, if you wish your image to match either width *or* height, you need to declare both. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XxgkG/

```
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Note this will not work in IE6 and is shaky in IE7. If you're coding for these sad, lonely browsers you should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442521/how-to-make-css-max-width-in-ie6-and-7).

Comment: IE6 ignores min-width, max-height and max-width , so you would batter use width instead of max-width.

Comment: True – however if the goal is to only increase width up to an image's natural maximum size you cannot accomplish that with width alone. If you're coding for IE 6 you'd probably need a JS fallback. Here's an answer with an IE6 hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442521/how-to-make-css-max-width-in-ie6-and-7

Comment: see this : http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/AtxYb/2/

try changing max-width  to width and see the difference

Comment: Yeah, however that doesn't do what the OP wants if the image's container has a set width: http://jsfiddle.net/emYtQ/1/ It stretches the image.

Comment: This only takes into account the width. What if the container was wide, but not very tall?

Answer (score 1):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/AtxYb/)

```
 img{height:auto;width:100%;}
```

Try re-sizing the window - The image will take up the maximum space .

Comment: I don't think this is what the poster wants: "Obviously if it's a very small image I don't want it to stretch, I never want any of the images to stretch". Your solution stretches the images beyond 100% of their original size.

Comment: A nice solution would need to know the image dimensions and adjust the CSS accordingly.  Perhaps a jQuery action along with some CSS scaling would do the trick.