# ie6 img width:auto doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have an image element which is dynamically changed, and if necessary dynamically re-sized to fit its container.

My current process is:

1. reset image:

   ```
   // make sure the 'load' event is re-triggered
   img.src = "";
   // reset dimensions
   img.style.width = "auto";
   img.style.height = "auto";
   ```
2. set its new source and wait for it to load

   ```
   img.src = newImageSource;
   ```
3. in the images `onload` handler, the size is tested and if necessary, altered:

   ```
   img.style.width = newWidth + "px";
   ```

this is repeated as often as the image is changed (infinite).

This works fine for all browsers tested (ie7,8,9,10, FF, chrome) however ie6 setting width/height to "auto" seems to resize the element to around 25 x 25 px regardless of the actual image's dimensions.

So; is there a way to reset the images dimensions to the equivalent of "auto" so that the dimensions of the image subsequently loaded determines the elements dimensions for ie6?

Comment: i cannot control my client's client's soe; do you post this for every ie6 question?

Comment: Suggest this to your client: http://www.ie6countdown.com/ (© 2013 Microsoft)

Comment: you think i haven't? get constructive please.

Comment: I read somewhere you could use `_width: 0;` IE6 should auto size the content. Might be worth giving a try.

Comment: @pstanton: why are venting your clients frustration on me. I was wondering if ie6 is still out there. :(

Comment: Check to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442521/how-to-make-css-max-width-in-ie6-and-7

Comment: Just a question why are you setting the image dimensions? if you left it without value wouldn't it be adjusted automatically?

Comment: @RohitAzad I can't see how that helps

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue via script i've tried `img.style._width = "0";` and same for height to no avail. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I seem to remember that you can do `img.style.width = "";` instead of `"auto"` or the value in pixels. However, I do apologise if it's not right. It's a _long_ time ago since I had to do anything with IE6...

Comment: @MrLister put it in an answer

Comment: Oh, OK. I had no idea if it would work, since I don't have IE6 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can write

```
img.style.width = "";
```

to set the width to its default value of `auto`. Apparently `img.style.width = "auto";` doesn't work the same way.

Comment: thanks, this appears to be cross-browser too so no need for user agent check